# Same microsecond is printed out when using datetime.now() in pycharm

Tags: python, datetime, pycharm

```
def withdraw(self,pin,value):
    if self.checkCode(pin):
        if value <= self.balance:
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            history.update({current_time:-value})
            self.balance -= value
            print("Successfully withdrawn " + str(value) + " euros from your account.")
        else:
            print("Not enough balance")
    else:
        print("Wrong pin code.Try again.")

if checkAcc.checkCode(int(pin)):
checkAcc.withdraw(1234,2000)
checkAcc.withdraw(1234,4000)
checkAcc.withdraw(1234,1000)]
```

I am new to python and I am currently doing this bank account project in pycharm. However, the datetime.now() doesn't seem to print out different microseconds and hence the values in history is constantly being overwritten whenever i call the withdraw method. However, when i run this code in IDLE, it works fine by printing out different microsecond for every withdraw method called. Does anyone know how to fix it? The outcome of the code above in pycharm is as in the image in the link provided. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `datetime.now()` will depend on an OS call to get the current time, and OS timers don't have very good resolution.

Comment: I don't see any print out of timestamps with equal microseconds? could you clarify where / under which circumstances you observe the issue?

Comment: @MarkRansom I dont really know about OS, is it different in different IDE??

Comment: @MrFuppes the timestamp is the key in a dictionary in this case, and the money withdrawn is the value to the key, for each withdraw method called.

Comment: you could add a very short wait after the dict update, e.g. `time.sleep(0.001)` - note that this will stall all of your code for that time.